# Adding dates and time to bundled templates in PhpStorm

Tags: templates, phpstorm, velocity

I want to add some data to the default phpDoc comments. In this case, the one for classes. I can add string text, but some of the conventional variables do not work. See below:

```
/**
 * Class ${NAME}
  #if (${NAMESPACE}) * @package ${NAMESPACE}
#end
 * @copyright ${YEAR}
 * @date ${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}
 * @description 
 * @updated ${DATE}:${TIME}
 * @version 1.0
 */
```

This just renders out the `${TAG}` in the comment, and it is not replaced with the date or time like it does in custom templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All supported template variables are listed in the bottom list (below template text) -- the date/time variables are not in that list for **Includes templates** -- such variables are only available at **File templates**.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18015
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17507

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

**P.S.**
If you use Include template inside File template then `${DATE}` and alike will be parsed just fine. For example (`PHP Class` file template):

```
<?php
#parse("PHP File Header.php")

#if (${NAMESPACE})
namespace ${NAMESPACE};

#end
#parse("PHP Class Doc Comment.php")
class ${NAME}
{

}
```